# Facade Pattern for rxjs streams for cleaner Angular architecture?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, rxjs, facade

**For context:**

I'm working on an Angular 15 app, where I distinguish between smart and dumb components. My smart components do have connection to services, whereas the dumb components only communicate via Inputs and Outputs with the smart component and do not get any services injected.

Within the smart components I use a reactive declarative (rxjs) approach to react to events. However, by now these smart components involve many reactive streams which makes the component bloated.

As these smart components are kind of "collectors" of many events and the "access" to the api service, I don't see reasonable way how I could break up the component into smaller parts.

**Question:**

I was thinking about using Design Patterns, e.g. the Facade Pattern, to declutter the component by putting the reactive streams into a separate service and the component would only have to subscribe to the final observables and handle the side effects (like UI updates).

However, I wonder if this would be a smart approach and if there are better ways to deal with this situation.

**Example of complex smart component:**

```
class MySmartComponent {
  // ... several @Input and private members

  // Multiple RxJS streams to handle different scenarios
  dataFromRoute$: Data[] = this.route.url.pipe(/* ... */);
  dataAfterAdded$: Data[] = this.addDataButtonClick$.pipe(/* ... */);
  dataAfterMore$: Data[] = this.getMoreDataButtonClick$.pipe(/*...*/);
  dataAfterDeleted$: Data[] = this.deleteDataButtonClick$.pipe(/* ... */);

  data$: Observable<Data[]> = merge(
        this.dataFromRoute$,
        this.dataAfterAdded$,
        this.dataAfterMore$
        this.dataAfterDeleted$,
    ).pipe(/*...*/);

  searchInput$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(''); // user can search/filter Data

  // subscription only to this Observable via async pipe in template!
  filteredData$: Observable<Data[] | null> = combineLatest([
        this.data$,
        this.dataSearchInput$,
    ]).pipe(

  // function calls by child components
  onSearchInputChange(value: string) { /* ... */ }
  onDeleteDataClick(event: SomeEvent) { /* ... */ }
  // ... more logic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally using a separate service for managing data is a valid approach. You can create "MySmartService", make it non-singleton, and declare it as a provider for MySmartComponent. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MySmartService {
   ...
}

@Component({
    providers: [MySmartService]
})
class MySmartComponent {
    constructor(private mySmartService: MySmartService) {}
}
```

This way your MySmartService will only be created when `MySmartComponent` is created. Also, you can add `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook to `MySmartService` to complete your data streams. It's going to work because `MySmartService` will be destroyed along with `MySmartComponent`.

I wouldn't call it `Facade` thought. `Facade` pattern is a structured API for several services or some complicated structure. In this case, we only have one component with different API calls / data streams.

Perhaps it makes sense to create several additional services - one for API , one for user events, etc. So every service has one purpose and follows single responsibility principle.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply! I created a StackBlitz were I did that and put state management + crud operations in there. What do you think? How could it be improved? You can fork and edit the StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-declarative-state-management-bnszzg?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Hey, you're welcome) I added some services, see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-declarative-state-management-qle87w?file=src%2Fcrud-operations%2Fdata-access%2Fstore-data.service.ts
I didn't refactor the initial service, so this is not a working example but I hope the idea is clear. I also added comments to the code. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Oh wow cool, that looks pretty neat! I will fork and finish the TODOs in the upcoming days. However, I don't fully understand the seperation of "manage-data" and "store-data". What benefit is there?
Also dataSearchInput$ is in both:
- in ManageDataService it is implemented in the filteredData$ Stream
- and in the StoreDataService there is a TODO comment saying to implement it. What is the correct place for that?

Comment: Also, before seeing your StackBlitz, I redesigned my earlier version to make it more organised while keeping it reactive declarative. I managed to do it by having only one action$ Subject as access point to the FeatureStateService and one state$ Observable which is the Single Source of Truth for the feature. The smart component subscribes only to this single Observable and gets updated once actions are made or the url changes. My goal was to create an architecture which can be applied as a solid structure for most features. I'd be very happy to hear what you think of it! :)

Comment: <I don't fully understand the separation of "manage-data" and "store-data". What benefit is there?> -


"store-data" is a CRUD service that contains CRUD operations for _dataStore$. In real application it can be implemented using some data store solution such as NgRx. The benefit is to separate data mutations from the other logic. Also it can be moved to backend and managed there - depends on the app.


<Also dataSearchInput$ is in both> - 
Yeah, my mistake, removed it from StoreDataService, it should be only in ManageDataService

Comment: <I'd be very happy to hear what you think of it! :)> - I believe you've used another stackblitz? I don't see these changes in the original one. Anyway good luck with making a clean architectural sample) I'll be happy to have a look and maybe suggest something if you share it after you finish

Comment: Hey thank you a lot for your continuous answers, really appreciate it :) Yeah, totally forgot to append the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-declarative-state-management-exmqih?file=src%2Fcrud-operations%2Fdata-access%2Ffeature-state.service.ts

Comment: Btw I know it is quite rxjs heavy, but I hope this would make the rest of the code much easier to write since everything has it's place). Most importantly if you want to add a feature you just have to think about what Action it is, and how the ApiCallService + FeatureStateService have to react. More precisely api calls are made in the mergeMap() and state changes are made within the .scan(). That's it. No need to make big changes across components, just there. At least that's my theory/hope ^^ Really interested what you have to say about it, as it seems you are more experienced!

Comment: Hey) Just checked your code. Have you thought about using some state management solution, for example, NgRx? Look - you have a state (SSOT), initial state, actions, kind of reducer ( updateState method ). Your solution looks like a custom, simplified implementation of the Redux pattern. I'd suggest trying something out of the box - so you can benefit from a well-tested, standardized library. It's easier to debug using Store dev tools and it has many other advantages over the custom code...

Comment: Btw I don't want to discourage you to write custom solutions like that - it's very useful for practice and understanding state management patterns. But for a real application I would use existing state management tools, it's just more convenient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to look at the code and letting me know! I thought about NgRx, but I also heard it's not very easy to learn and might create unnecessary overhead. I fear that it might make the code more complicated, especially for beginners. My solution is not super easy as well, but most complexity is inside the state observable. Before that/once inside the switch statement, it's easy again and adding new features seem to be relatively straightforward so far. If I find problems with it, I'll definitely consider NgRx. In case you saw any problems with it, happy to hear from you :)

Comment: You're welcome) I'd suggest trying your solution in a real application, with real HTTP calls. Maybe make UI a bit more complicated, add several entities to the business model, and then add some relations between them ( i.e one-to-one, one-to-many ... ). Then it should be easy to detect problems. Maybe you'll have to make your solution more abstract, make some base feature class, or something like that. Good luck)